# Java Weblauncher - JNLP issues

Tags: javascript, java, jar, jnlp

There is an application in our business that is downloaded via an IE Web portal and every 30 days you need to go back into the web portal and rerun one section of it to renew the lease...

It dumps a JNLP file in %temp% which I have managed to extract (I too have been able to save the file using Edge) but when you click on the JNLP file it says **"Unable to launch PDT (See log for details)** but it launches from this portal fine. I am hoping to package this and automate the renewal before it expires but cant have users logging on to this web portal every 30 days. How do I call this JNLP file with the relevant switches to run successfully ? and where are these PDT log files?? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Unable to launch PDT" is your application error. How are we supposed to help with that? Have you, ahem, *seen the log for details*?

Comment: Is the unable to launch PDT the app and not Java as it is launching from a JNLP file. Also Where are the logs specifically for this? I did a search using agent ransack for that exact string and nothing found.